# Was PhiCorp using Time Lord technology?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

In the episode *Dead of Night* of *Torchwood: Miracle Day*, when Jack, Rex and Gwen infiltrate the PhiCorp warehouse, Jack comments that it's "bigger on the inside". Assuming it just doesn't look bigger, but physically is bigger, this would be a common trait we see with a key piece of Time Lord Technology.

I know this technology has been possessed by someone else other than the Time Lords once: the Genesis Ark, which was built by the Time Lords but ended up in the hands of the Daleks. Was this warehouse also built using Time Lord technology? If so, where did PhiCorp or the Three Families get it? The only instance of this technology I can think of, other than the Time Lords, is the Genesis Ark itself, but this was sucked into the Void.

Comment: The Dalek did not steal technology for the Genesis Ark. It was mentioned in the episode that the Genesis Ark was a prison ship created by the time lords.

Comment: @NoNameNeeded432 oh yhe that's right, i've corrected it saying that the tech got into the hands (or plunger) of the Daleks since it's i assume the Daleks having it was what the Time Lords had wanted (even if a criminal can't open a prison you don't give them control of it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would guess not.**

I don't think it's explicitly mentioned, but I think it's being played as a casual reference for people who are familiar with Doctor Who, not a major plot point.

At this point, Jack et al. are trying to work out what’s caused The Miracle. Although Jack has never seen it used this way<sup>1</sup>, Time Lord technology could easily be responsible. If he seriously thought PhiCorp had transcendental engineering, I’d expect him to make more of a point of it. That it’s brushed off as a casual remark makes me think that he doesn’t seriously believe Time Lord science is involved; he’s just emphasising the size of the warehouse.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Although you could count his resurrection at Rose’s hands as somewhat similar.</sup>

Comment: Haven't rewatched lately, but as far as I remember, most of the warehouse was underground, so when you looked at the building from the outside, it was really smaller than the space you could see inside.

Comment: Yes, ironically the entire Miracle stems from Rose's TARDIS powers, so arguably the entire thing is down to Time Lord technology. That and the random thingie in the Earth that came out of nowhere plot-wise...